# sklearn: How to get column indexes deleted by model.transform from original dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataframe

I'm trying to apply future selection. The problem is that using the whole dataframe raises the memory error. So I've decided to cut my dataframe to be able to apply use next future selection:

```
# this is original dataframes
X_full = df_train[df_train.columns[0:size]] # 76000(rows)*300(cols)
y_full = df_train[[len(df_train.columns)-1]] # 76000(rows)*1(col)
```

`y_full` contains 0 and 1, and the number 1's are below 5%. All other columns contains only numbers, but we don't know that they mean.

```
#this is way, I reduce the number of rows to 10%
test_frac = 0.10
count = len(X_full)
X = X_full.iloc[-int(count*test_frac):]
y = y_full.iloc[-int(count*test_frac):]

#Then I use Linear models penalized with the L1 norm to reduce the dimensionality of the data
lsvc = LinearSVC(C=0.01, penalty="l1", dual=False).fit(X, y)
model = SelectFromModel(lsvc, prefit=True)
X_new = model.transform(X)
print "X_new.shape", X_new.shape
print X_new
```

The problem is that I need to get list of colums, which were deleted, to get rid of them from the original dataframe. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you tell us more about rhe dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`SelectFromModel.get_support()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html). Per the docs, it can return either (1) a boolean array with length equal to the number of *all* features (2) integer indices of the included features:

> An index that selects the retained features from a feature vector. If indices is False, this is a boolean array of shape [# input features], in which an element is True iff its corresponding feature is selected for retention. If indices is True, this is an integer array of shape [# output features] whose values are indices into the input feature vector.